# D3.js: Align X-Axis to specific value on Y-Axis (e.g. the origin)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want something a simple as this:

http://alex.nt.fh-koeln.de/Bilder/wlet1.jpg

The Axis are aligned to the origin. However, I could only figure out how to adjust the axis in terms of the width/height using transform:

```
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height/2 + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
```

This will put the X-axis in the middle of the graph, which is not necessarily the origin. I guess there is a simple solution, but I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: Instead of translating by a fixed value, translate e.g. by the minimum value of the x scale passed to the scale.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Sorry, but I don't see how this will help me find the position of the zero value of the other axis?

Comment: Well, you can determine the difference between 0 and the left end by taking the difference between the values 0 and the extreme value are mapped to (sorry, I forgot to add the "difference" bit). That gives you the number of pixels between left end of axis and 0. Translating by that should get you to 0. Similar for the other axis.